# ODBC select query with text field return no record

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, adodb, prepared-statement

I have in mysql table - products (product_id int, name varchar, description text).
I use latest ODBC driver to connect to mysql from excel (VBA) with parametrized query:

```
dim DCONT as ADODB.Connection
set DCONT = new ADODB.Connection
DCONT.open "DSN=myDSN"

set cmd = new ADODB.command
cmd.commandtext = "SELECT product_id, name FROM products WHERE name LIKE ?" 
set param1=cmd.createparameter("@strName", advarchar, adparaminput, 30, "%testvalue%"
cmd.parameters.append param1
cmd.activeconnection = DCONT
dim rsRecords = new ADODB.recordset
rsRecords.open cmd
```

This code return requested records correctly. 
When I change commandtext to (query included the field description from table (field type text))

```
cmd.commandtext = "SELECT product_id, name, description FROM products WHERE name LIKE ?"
```

it returns No record. 
In the same way when I use this query

```
cmd.commandtext = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE ?"
```

it returns No record.

Next code without parametrized query returns requested record. It means there is a problem with returning records only by use parametrized query.

```
dim DCONT as ADODB.Connection
set DCONT = new ADODB.Connection
DCONT.open "DSN=myDSN"

set cmd = new ADODB.command
cmd.commandtext = "SELECT product_id, name, description FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%testvalue%'"
cmd.activeconnection = DCONT
dim rsRecords = new ADODB.recordset
rsRecords.open cmd
```

Any advice please?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but `WHERE name LIKE ?` is essentially returning *everything*? Or you want records that have a question `?`. In that case, try `Like %?%`

Comment: Try qualifying `name` as an explicit field identifier (`"name")`- I don't *think* it's a reserved keyword in MySQL or ODBC, but I've had issues with it before.

Comment: WHERE name Like ?  = Parameter (odbc doesn't support named parameters)

Comment: There is no problem with field identifier (name). There is a problem when I want to return field od type text. It returns no records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution -> Need to upgrade to the latest MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver, version 8.00.13.00, then everything works.